# Geting content from txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a quite coding beginner and I am struggling a lot to get data from a .txt with Javascript. I have a really simple txt file.
I would like to read the file with Javascript and store the info ideally into an array.

Here is my txt content:

```
"Italy":  30,
"France":  28,
"Netherlands":  1,
"Germany":  14,
"Greece":  4,
"Spain":  3,
"others":  12
```

What I manage to do after checking all the posible forums is the following. I can select the txt file and display the content with this following code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style type="text/css"> 
     #filecontents { 
          border:double; 
       overflow-y:scroll; 
       height:400px; 
     } 
</style>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="FileReaderLogic.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
     Please Select text file of which contents are to be read: 
      <input type="file" id="txtfiletoread" />
    <div>The File Contents are as below:</div> 
    <div id="filecontents">
        <script>ReadText()</script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**FileReaderLogic.js:**

```
window.onload = function ReadText() { 

//Check the support for the File API support 
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

var fileSelected = document.getElementById('txtfiletoread');
fileSelected.addEventListener('change', function (e) { 
     //Set the extension for the file 
     var fileExtension = /text.*/; 
     //Get the file object 
     var fileTobeRead = fileSelected.files[0];
    //Check of the extension match 
     if (fileTobeRead.type.match(fileExtension)) { 
         //Initialize the FileReader object to read the 2file 
         var fileReader = new FileReader(); 
         fileReader.onload = function (e) { 
             var fileContents = document.getElementById('filecontents'); 
             fileContents.innerText = fileReader.result; 
         } 
         fileReader.readAsText(fileTobeRead); 
     } 
     else { 
         alert("Please select text file"); 
     }
   }, false);} 
else { 
    alert("Files are not supported"); 
}
}
```

This works fine but I do not manage to change this code in oder to enter directly inthe code the file name/path (no button and no selection from the user needed) and store the file data into a variable or an array.

Could you please help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: Try to use node js for any server side JavaScript coding.

Comment: `enter directly inthe code the file name/path` from a regular browser you can't for security reasons.  Can you image somebody writing a website that got access to something like `\osdir\password.txt` or something like that.

Comment: Having the user agree to the process by selecting the file manually is mandatory, you can't automate it - if you could you would be allowing any random website access to local files which is strictly prohibited.  If you want to store data on the client investigate *localStorage*.

Comment: You could use Require.js and load the file directly in your project.

Comment: FYI: You have a script that calls `ReadText()` at the bottom of the page, so that it will happen automatically. You also have a `load` callback that invokes `ReadText()`. You shouldn't have both of them as it causes the same thing to happen twice. Remove the `window.onload = ` and just allow the script at the bottom of the page to invoke the function.

Comment: Just trying to be sure... Where is the text file stored - on client machine (where the page is addressed on browser) or server(where `FileReaderLogic.js` also resides)?

Comment: thanks for these answers. I see the point and understand the security issue. I am quite sure there is an easy solution to my problem though. maybe the .txt solution is not the right one. I use a powershell script to read how many subfolders are created in a folder and sort it by country (based on the subfolders name). I write this data into a txt file. And now I want to read, work and display this info on a web browser. The powershell script will be hosted on my cumputer and will run each time my computr starts. The output file (txt) and the .js will be on a shared server. So everything local.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you can't for obvious security reasons.

Now, this kind of question often come from a wrong point of view on what problem you have and how to solve it.

Quickest way from where you are to make it work, **if** I understand your needs (it's a big if ^^) :

1-rename your .txt file as .js

2-make its content a js Object like so :

```
var country_code={
  "Italy":  30,
  "France":  28,
  "Netherlands":  1,
  "Germany":  14,
  "Greece":  4,
  "Spain":  3,
  "others":  12
};
```

3-include your js file in your html

```
<script src="./script/country.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And there you have your array variable with all your values from your file, usable in your main page.

For example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test='';
for (var country in country_code) {
  test += country+':'+country_code[country]+'<br />';
}
document.body.innerHTML = test; 
</script>
```

Does it help ?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Basically what I have:

 ** Output file from a Powershell script. Powershell script run each time my computer starts and update the output file (output format is now .txt but maybe not the best)
* I want to work on the output file and display the result on a web browser (I thought js would be the best)
* The script run locally, the output file, the js and the .html will be saved locally on a shared server
* so I just want to share with my colleagues the .html path, that they put it into the web browser and that they see the results

Comment: Then it's the way to go. Make your powershell script output a .js file with `var country_code={` at the start and `};` at the end, put the path to this file in a `<script>` tag in your html and from there you can work on `country_code` to display what you want in the html (look up js object manipulations, and ask if you're lost). I added a little example to illustrate.

Comment: you absolutely made my day or even my week. It works and it is exactly what I was looking for. I knew trere was an easy way to do it and you found it. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: With pleasure ! Please don't forget to check my answer as accepted (little check sign left to the answer) for others to come (and to show mister anonymous downvoter how wrong he is :p). BTW, Scott Marcus's answer is a nice one too if you ever need dynamic file call.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished much simpler with an **[AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)** (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) call for the text file's contents and then modify the text file just a little bit so that the data is stored in **[JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)** format.

You can hard-code the path to the text file into the configuration of the AJAX component.

Also, your data in the text file is more suited to a JavaScript `Object`, rather than an `Array` because arrays don't allow for setting up key/value pairs without getting into nested arrays. Objects are data structures that store key/value pairs and, as a matter of fact, if you simple wrap your text file's contents with `{` and `}`, you will have the syntax for an object converted to JSON format.

**data.txt** (This is a string that conforms to the JSON data format)

```
{
 "Italy":  30,
 "France":  28,
 "Netherlands":  1,
 "Germany":  14,
 "Greece":  4,
 "Spain":  3,
 "others":  12
}
```

**HTML** (Note: your  tag was not located properly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="FileReaderLogic.js"></script>
    <style> 
      #filecontents { 
        border:double; 
        overflow-y:scroll; 
        height:400px; 
      } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
    Please Select text file of which contents are to be read: 
    <div>The File Contents are as below:</div> 
    <div id="filecontents"></div>
    <script>ReadText()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**FileReaderLogic.js**

```
var dataObj = null; // Will hold data after AJAX call completes

function ReadText() {
  // Create instance of XHR 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Set up event callback functions
  xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);

  // Configure the request. Replace pathToTextFile with a relative
  // path to a file (in the same domain as this file). 
  xhr.open("GET", pathToTextFile, true);

  // Request body will be plain text
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");

  // Make the request:
  xhr.send(null);
}

// Success Callback:
function transferComplete(evt) {
  // Place the response in the HTML placeholder:
  document.getElementById("filecontents").textContent = xhr.responseText;

  // Turn text file content into object
  dataObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 

  // Now, use the object as you like:
  console.log(dataObj.Italy); // 30

  // This will print all the key/value pairs
  for(var key in dataObj){
     console.log(key + " = " + dataObj[key]);
  }
}

// Error callback:
function transferFailed(evt) {
  console.log("An error occurred while processing the request.");
}
```